# where does zxing check for Luminance, finder pattern and error correction level

Tags: java, zxing

Anyone knows where does zxing library (in Java) check for Luminance and other factors that would affect the readability of a QR code?
For example, if the luminance is lower than some number, it will show a massage saying "Luminance is low". Where exactly is this number checked in the zxing library? And also where are the other factors that have been checked for scannability?
I have looked into LuminanceSource and Detector libraries, but didn't found that specific number or function checking for these.
Also what are the all factors that I need to check to make sure the QR code is scannable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look at the source? It's pretty clear. `LuminanceSource` is not the place; look at `HybridBinarizer` for luminance. There is no such thing as a "check for scannability". `qrcode.Detector` calls `FinderPatternFinder` to locate finder patterns. I don't know what you mean by error correction level but the `common.reedsolomon` package performs correction, as you can probably guess just by the name.

Comment: I have almost looked every file in the library, but since there are too many of them, I got confused. Thank you for pointing that out. This is really helpful.